# How to tell if a program or process tried to print or print info

Tags: windows, permissions, printer, forensics

I'm trying to work with third party support on a financial program called Mercury. The program says it has successfully printed a report through its "scheduler", but never physically prints anything. It worked about a year ago, but not since. It accesses the printer in a convoluted way that even the support staff can't seem to explain to me, but basically it's not showing a job going through spool/queue on the server hosting the software, the server the printers are shared from, or the computers running the software. If there is a job created at all, it seems it's either immediately rejected without warning or disappears as if it had printed. The support team wants me to prove it's not a permissions issue, but I see nothing wrong with printer permissions and there are no errors at any point in the printing process.

**Is there a good way to prove whether or not the software is even trying to print correctly without seeing a job in queue?** I'm willing to look for logs, run third party tools, etc.

I also don't see any event logs in Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational on either server or computer.

This is a Windows Server 2012 environment with Windows7/8 workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

Connect the driver (on the PC that does the printing) to FILE: from Printer Properties > Ports. It will then ask for a file name and you can inspect that file.

Another thing you can try is to stop the normal print queue files from being deleted. With the normal port selected, go to Devices & Printers. Right-click the printer and select Printer Properties. Click the Advanced tab and then tick the box for "Keep printed documents". That way the print job will not be deleted from the queue. This needs to be done on whatever system the queue is. If the PC prints via a server, then it's the server. If the PC prints direct (TCP/IP, USB, parallel,,,) then you need to do it on that PC.

Of course, all of this assumes that the program prints using Windows drivers. If it doesn't then all bets are off.

Comment: I'm trying to schedule the team to work with me to make sure I don't mess with other documents printing when I do this. Hopefully, I will be able to let you know what happened by the end of the week. - Thanks!

Comment: We sort-of fixed it. It will print now, just not using the right fonts. I had to install the print device directly to the server instead of using a UNC path in the software and that seemed to work. I'm giving you the answer because those would have helped troubleshooting... and because you answered. Thanks!